# IoC dependency Injection determining the class from Ajax

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am an IoC beginner, I am facing a serious problem with implementing the IoC dependency injection.

I have an application which is having 2 datasources, the data could be coming from Solr or from the database. I have 2 pages, Inventory page which is displaying all the vehicles for a dealer with a quickSearch engine getting the lookups from Solr such as Make, Model ,... and display them in dropdownlists, the second page is VehicleDetails that present a particular vehicle plus the lookups such as Make, Model but the data should be coming from the DataBase.

I have created LookupServiceSolr and LookupServiceSQL implementing one interface ILookupService in CastleControllerFactory:

```
_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Services.ILookupService>().ImplementedBy(typeof(MCI.Services.LookupServiceSQL)).Named("LookupSQL"));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Services.ILookupService>().ImplementedBy(typeof(MCI.Services.LookupServiceSolr)).Named("LookupSolr"));
```

The InventoryController will use the LookupServiceSolr and the VehicleDetailsController will use the LookupServiceSQL, so I did register them this way:

```
_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Presentation.Web.Controllers.InventoryController>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("LookupService").Eq("LookupSolr")).LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Presentation.Web.Controllers.VehicleDetailsController>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("LookupService").Eq("LookupSql")).LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));
```

and the constructors of InventoryController and the VehicleDetailsController having LookupService as a parameter and all working fine at runtime which means vehicleDetailsController will have LookupService implemented by LookupServiceSQL and InventoryController will have LookupService implemented by LookupServiceSOlr.

My questions are the following :
1- Am I implementing the IoC dependency injection in the right way?
2- This is my main question, if I have LookupController which has IlookupService in the constructor and the VehicleDetailsController has LookupController in the constructor, and I registered them in the container this way :

```
_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Services.ILookupService>().ImplementedBy(typeof(MCI.Services.LookupServiceSQL)).Named("LookupSQL"));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Services.ILookupService>().ImplementedBy(typeof(MCI.Services.LookupServiceSolr)).Named("LookupSolr"));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Presentation.Web.Controllers.LookupController>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("lookupService").Eq("LookupSolr")).Named("Vehicle").LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Presentation.Web.Controllers.LookupController>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("lookupService").Eq("LookupSQL")).Named("Details").LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Presentation.Web.Controllers.InventoryController>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("lookupController").Eq("Vehicle")).LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));

_Container.Register(Component.For<MCI.Presentation.Web.Controllers.VehicleDetailsController>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("lookupController").Eq("Details")).LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient));
```

so actually this is my flow and it is all working fine :
InventoryController -> LookupController -> LookupServiceSolr.
VehicleDetailsController -> LookupController -> LookupServiceSQL.

My problem is that I have an Ajax post, the Make dropdownList will do an ajax posting on change and get the Model based on the make, I want to call the method in the LookupController right away from the view and not passing through the vehicleDetailsController which knows that my lookupController has a LookupServiceSQL, I want the contrainer to know that I want the LookupServiceSQL not the LookupServiceSolr.
Is there any way to do it or is there a different idea to solve this problem?

Please I need a help as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance,
Alaa

Comment: please format the code snippets properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overengineering it a bit. Instead of configuring the LookupController to have one dependency injected for LookupService (one set of conditions for LookupSolr and another for LookupSql), why not inject both LookupServices to your controller, and just use the one which matches your actions or parameters?

Change the registration keys to something like:

```
ServiceOverride.ForKey("lookupServiceSolr").Eq("lookupSolr"),
ServiceOverride.ForKey("lookupServiceSQL").Eq("lookupSQL"),
```

... then you can use it a bit more simply:

```
public class LookupController : ControllerBase
{
    ILookupService LookupServiceSolr= null;
    ILookupService LookupServiceSQL= null;

    public LookupController(ILookupService lookupServiceSolr, ILookupService lookupServiceSQL)
    {
        LookupServiceSolr= lookupServiceSolr;
        LookupServiceSQL= lookupServiceSQL;
    }

    // then use the one you want based on parameters or type of call

}
```